The front of my home has a rough-cut brick exterior. How would I seal the gaps around light to prevent bugs/water intrusion?
I don't like the look and obvious gaps between the (shallow) light base and the house.  I get spider intrusions and am concerned with water intrusion due to sideways rain and/or power washing.  Other than just gooping a ton of sealant, is there a method to fabricate a flat surface mount for the light that will also the rough texture of the brick and seal all the gaps?
In the photo you'll see what I'm looking at.  The wires come through the brick and that mounting plate is flush on the brick.
Same question for doorbell.


Caulking seems the obvious solution.

@keshlam   Seems big for just caulking.

Shove in some backer rod, then caulk? The alternative I see is dismounting the fixture and applying mortar to produce a level surface to mount the lamp against. Note: If you do caulk, leave a weep hole at the bottom so any water that does get in van drain back out.
